# Why do we differentiate y' or p totally not partially while solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While solving the first order ODE second degree ODE , for example
$$y=2xy'+\frac{1}{y'}$$
We call y' as p and we differentiate wrt x 
$$p=2p+(2x-\frac{1}{p^2})\frac{dp}{dx}$$
My question is : Is p function of x only ? I think it is function in both x and y .. So why do we write the total differentiation of p wrt x  (Not partial differentiation) ?

Comment: I do not understand , can you clarify more ? do you mean since we write y in one side , we assume that all terms in the other side are function in x only ?

Comment: it is a D'Alembert equation

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsEquation.html

Answer (score 1):

In the context at hand there is one independent variable, namely $x$, and there are several functions of $x$, among them the unknown function $x\mapsto y(x)$ and its derivative $x\mapsto y'(x)$. For the latter a new name $p(\cdot)$ is introduced. Your ODE then becomes
$$y(x)=2xp(x)+{1\over p(x)}\ .$$
Differentiating this with respect to $x$ and replacing $y'(x)$ by $p(x)$ leads to your second formula.

Comment: I am convinced with the answer , but I have another question related to this :   in case we solve the DE for x , i.e. taking x in one side then differentiate wrt y , we will have dp/dy ..although p or y' is function of x as we said in the above example , why do we consider p as function of y (only) when solving for x!